# IIS Application Configuration Error

Tags: asp.net, iis, virtual-directory

Error Message: "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

This is the error I get with an application I build in Visual Studios Express 2012 (for Web). It is using .Net Framework 4.5 which I recently installed onto the computer. I first created a Virtual Directory and got this error. So, I looked up possible solutions and have done the following:

1. I cleaned the application in VS. No change.
2. I deleted the obj folder. No change.
3. I converted the Virtual Directory to an Application. No change.

So far, these are the only solutions I have managed to find and none of them worked for me. Could anyone give me some other ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that you're hitting the website and application that you think you are? Check the logs just to be sure. It has bitten me before...

Comment: Is the target ASP.NET platform in IIS correct

Comment: @northben Not really sure what you mean..

Comment: @Pleun Yes, checked and double checked. Still no luck. :(

Comment: Do you see log entries in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\<siteID>\ when you try to access your site?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when a web.config file defines a value for which the parent has already defined and children are not allowed to define themselves.  For example, you could have in your application's web.config an authentication value of 'mode="Windows"' but the parent has already defined the value as 'Forms'.  Comment out all web.config values except for your appSettings and connectionStrings and see if the site works.  If it does, start uncommenting the lines you've commented out one by one to figure out which section is causing the problem.

**Edit for comment**

Your IIS setup is the problem.  You need to double check where the application directory is and whether an application (not virtual directory) has been properly set up in IIS.  IIS 7 now has websites, applications, and virtual directories.  You have a directory that is under a site but is not set up properly as an application.  And just creating a virtual directory out of the site's directory does not make it run in its own process space, ala websites and applications.

Comment: Did this and now it takes me to a directory instead of a physical site. When I try to go to the Home page, it says it cannot be found. I just recently started up working again and so I haven't been working with this stuff for a while. Thank you for being patient with me

Comment: Well, I thought I set it up right. Here's what it is currently:
Folder 'Sites' > Default Web Site > Application 'SiPrac' > files for SiPrac application
SiPrac was originally created as a Virtual Directory that pointed to the files containing the application I wanted to deploy. I then right clicked SiPrac and selected 'Convert to Application' and then selected the App Pool I created for testing (.Net Framework 4.0 and higher, Pipeline mode: Classic [and I even tried Integrated just to be sure]).
So where did I go wrong? What else do I have to do in IIS to get my application working?

Comment: Try completely removing the application from IIS and right clicking on the Default Web Site and adding an application.  Maybe something got messed up during the conversion.

Comment: Invalid Application Path.... I've been getting this for almost all of the Applications. I'm starting to get the feeling our IIS might be bugged. Is that even possible?!

Comment: So I just heard from my co-worker that has worked with our IIS more than me and he believes that our Default Web Site might have gotten bugged by one of the older SharePoint applications. So he had another Website created and told me to test me application on there. I just did and now it's working perfectly!!
I'm SO sorry to have wasted your time but I learn a LOT. I'd still like to figure out what's going on with Default but that I'll do myself. Thank you SO much for all your help!! :D